# jQuery - Next paragraph

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-selectors, paragraph

how can I use 'next' in this case? Doesn't work...

```
var that = $( ".class" ).next( "p" );
if (that.hasClass('active')) {

            that.slideUp('slow', function () {

                that.removeClass('active');

            });
        }
```

This should show the case: https://jsfiddle.net/4Lmuydak/

Comment: Please also post html

Comment: show your html code for reference.

Comment: What you want to achieve. Not that much clear with whatever description you have added so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach click event to `h3` elements and then toggle the visibility of next sibling p element:

```
$('h3').click(function(){
    $(this).next('p').slideToggle('slow',function(){
       $(this).toggleClass("active")
    })
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/t1opgjck/)**

Comment: p:first doesn't work correctly... https://jsfiddle.net/8xL5oesu/ I just want to when I click on some h3 to show p under it

Comment: It's still the same :)

Comment: @AnnieTheCross: sorry..shared wrong link. check this https://jsfiddle.net/t1opgjck/

Comment: It's another solution - but it's work :) thanks a lot - I can use it

Comment: can you add this jsfiddle to your answer so I can mark it?